# ec2 is not pingable but not same case in previous

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, ubuntu-14.04, firewall, aws-security-group

I'm having ec2 machine in AWS, and it was pingable from till last night 6 Pm and suddenly it was not pingable. I googled and suggested add rule in security group.

I would like to know the reason why it was worked and why its stopped working suddenly?

Can someone let me know the reason?

Comment: Why do you wish to use PING? By default, the ICMP protocol is disabled in Security Groups, since it can expose information that could be used by an attacker. If you merely wish to test connectivity, you should use a protocol that the instance is serving, such as HTTP or SSH rather than permitting ICMP/Ping.

Comment: Check the instance monitoring by clicking the `status checks` to ensure your ec2 is passing reachability check